# Closing Tooltip when new one is opened

Tags: primefaces

I am looking for a possibilty to make a tooltip close automatically when a new one is opened. I am using Primefaces 6.1.

```
    <p:tooltip for="clientName" showEffect="clip" hideEvent="dblclick" 
     position="bottom">
```

At the moment it works like this: Mouseover on a label from my datatable and the tooltip opens. When I double click on the label which opened it, the tooltip disappears. But the problem is that I can accidently open like 30 tooltips at the time, just by moving over several datatable entrys.

Short: I only want a single tooltip to be opened at the time. But I dont want the tooltip to close by an MouseLeave event.

Im happy for any suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `onShow` or `onBeforeShow` attribute of the tooltip which is according to the PrimeFaces documentation (page 542 on in the 6.1 docs)

> **onShow**
>   Client side callback to execute after tooltip is shown.
>
> **beforeShow**
>   Client side callback to execute before tooltip is shown.
>   Returning false will prevent display.

In that you can call any javascript (jquery) to hide all other tooltips.

But why not use a showDelay of e.g. 500 ms instead of the defaul 150?

Comment: It is "almost" working. The problem is: When I use beforeShow, it doesnt even open anymore. When I use onShow, it closes as soon as it appeared. My js method is the following: 
function closeTooltip() {
 PF('tooltip-pd').hide();
}

The showDelay is a nice idea, but it doesnt change the fact that I only have to hover over the label for like 10ms to appear. When I set the delay to 1000ms it doesnt work for the "hover"-timer.

Any idea how I could make it work? But many thanks for your help :)

Comment: you need to explicitly 'return true' in the your javascript when using it with 'beforeShow'. Not returning anything (not sure you do) will be interpreted as 'false' I think and as you can read in the docs that prevents displaying

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I just tried adding a simple: return true; But I guess that's just wrong. I dont have any clue on how to work with js. Could you tell me what I actully have to write there? I gave the tooltip the ID "tooltip-pd".

Comment: I do not explicitly know and I do not have code available to try. Doing all this support from the top of my head. What if you use onShow?

Comment: It disappears after the opening animation. And if I move too fast over several datatable entrys, some stay and some disappear. Looks buggy.